# Windows Universal responsive design reposition

Tags: xaml, windows-10, win-universal-app, windows-10-mobile

So, I've just started working again with Windows apps and there are a few things that I can't get working as I want (probably because I coulnd't find any sample and Channel9 videos didn't cover my case).

Starting from [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn958435.aspx#responsive_design_techniques), I decided that the "reposition" technique is the one that fits my app when moving from a big screen to a smaller one.

What I did is using a `StackPanel` and changing its orientation using two `AdaptiveTrigger`s (one for 0 width and another one for 720, based on the table [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn958435.aspx#sizeclasses)).

This kinda works but there are some issues that I'll illustrate with some ugly paint-edited screenshots.

This is what happens when I'm in the `BigScreen` situation, where there's enough space to have both A and B on the same row. The problem here is that B should take the full remaining width, covering all the blue part.

[image: BigScreen]

The second issue is related to resizing. When there's not enough space, the green part gets cut instead of being resized (you can see that the right border disappeared). This didn't happen before using the `StackPanel` to make the layout responsive.

[image: HalfScreen]

Finally, when we are in the `SmallScreen` situation, orientation changes to be vertical and we have the same problem as the first one: green part's height doesn't fill the screen.

[image: SmallScreen]

Here's the `XAML` used for the page:

```
<Page
    x:Class="Page"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:WifiAnalyzerFinal.Views"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:mvvm="using:Mvvm"
    mc:Ignorable="d">        

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SmallScreen">
            <VisualState>
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="StackPanel.Orientation" 
                            Value="Vertical"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="BigScreen">
            <VisualState>
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="720"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="StackPanel.Orientation" 
                            Value="Horizontal"/>
                    <Setter Target="Rect.Width" 
                            Value="200"/>
                        <Setter Target="Rect.Height" 
                            Value="Auto"/>
                    </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"
                    Background="Blue"
                    x:Name="StackPanel">
            <Rectangle Fill="Red" 
                       Height="50"
                       x:Name="Rect"
                       Width="Auto"/>
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Stuff}"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                      HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                      Background="Green"
                      Width="Auto"
                      BorderBrush="DarkGreen"
                      BorderThickness="5"
                      Padding="5">
                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,5"/>
                    </Style>
                </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ListView>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Please note that without the `StackPanel` the green part fits the page as it should, covering all the available area. Unfortunately I couldn't came up with a better solution because there's no sample telling us how this technique should be implemented. I also tried using the new `RelativePanel` but it seems that the `AdaptiveTrigger`'s `Setter` doesn't work with attached properties like `RelativePanel.RightOf`.

Is there someone who's been successful is applying this technique without having to use code-behind?

EDIT:

I got this working using a `Grid` with 2 rows and 2 columns, with the `AdaptiveTrigger` moving all the content from row to column and viceversa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to change RelativePanel attached property values through setters. The syntax goes like this:

```
<Setter Target="SomeXAMLObject.(RelativePanel.RightOf)" Value="SomeOtherXAMLObject" />
```

Comment: I didn't knew of this syntax, I'll chek it out ASAP because this can make the code work using grids so that everything has the right size, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to use grid (instead of StackPanel) and define rows using proportional dimensions like:

```
`<Grid>
 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <RowDefinition width="2*"/>
  <RowDefinition width="3*"/>
  <RowDefinition width="1*"/>
 </Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid>`
```

Comment: Because moving to landscape would cause row 1 to be column 1 and I can't do this change using `Setter` as it doesn't work on attached properties (`Grid.Row` for example).

Comment: Check this link maybe it will help you with orientation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn495655.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this is not what I need. I don't have issues with orientation, I have issues with the responsive layout requested by Windows 10.